# Plotting strings as axis in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas DataFrame similar to :

```
Species  Count1 Count2 
AGREP      2       10
GYLEP      4       6
POAPRA     2       8
EUPESU     1       11
```

and I want to make a line plot of species vs. Count 1 with the x-axis being the species and the y-axis as Count 1.

I try to use the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(df.Species,df.Count1)
```

but this returns the error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float
```

I want to eventually only chose certain species to plot as well against both counts.  For example, I want to plot `AGREP` and `EUPESUS` on the x axis against both Count 1 and Count 2 as the y axis.  Again though, it won't plot the string as the axis name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set those strings as index and just use the `pandas.DataFrame` `.plot` method.

```
import pandas as pd

# your data
# ===================================

df


  Species  Count1  Count2
0   AGREP       2      10
1   GYLEP       4       6
2  POAPRA       2       8
3  EUPESU       1      11


# plot
# ===================================
df.set_index('Species').plot()
```

[image]

```
df.set_index('Species').loc[['AGREP', 'EUPESU']].plot()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can a set a specific column in your plot like this

```
import pandas as pd  
  
# assign data of lists.  
data = {'Species': ['AGREP', 'GYLEP', 'POAPRA', 'EUPESU'],
 'Count1': [2, 4, 2, 1],
 'Count2': [10, 6, 8, 11]}  
  
# Create DataFrame  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)  
df

# Output
  Species  Count1  Count2
0   AGREP       2      10
1   GYLEP       4       6
2  POAPRA       2       8
3  EUPESU       1      11

# Plot Count1 column while index is Species
df.set_index('Species')['Count1'].plot()
```

Plot Count1 column while index is Species:
[image: img]